# Can't select field where != null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

**controller:**

```
$view_log = DB::table('view')->where('user_id', '!=', null)
                             ->orderby('created_at', 'desc')
                             ->take(5)
                             ->get();
```

**view:**

```
@foreach ($view_log as $view)
    {{ $view->user_id }} viewed {{ $view->item_id }} {{ $view->created_at->diffForHumans() }}<br />
@endforeach
```

**view table structure:**

```
id | item_id | user_id | created_at
 1 |     930 |       3 | 
 2 |     930 |    null | 
 3 |     837 |       5 |
 4 |     378 |    null |
```

*null = guest, user_id = authenticated user*

**expected output:**

```
3 viewed 930 2 minutes ago
3 viewed 922 3 minutes ago
5 viewed 837 7 minutes ago
2 viewed 888 9 minutes ago
1 viewed 930 9 minutes ago
```

**error I get:**

```
InvalidArgumentException
Value must be provided.
```

**I assume it has to do with:**

```
->where('user_id', '!=', null)
```

How can I select only the rows in the table that contain a `user_id`?

Comment: Use `is not null` rather than `!= null`.

Comment: Try `where('user_id', 'IS NOT', null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
DB::table('table')->whereNotNull('column')->get();
```

**Source:** 
http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects

Also in SQL, `!= null` is supposed to be `IS NOT NULL`

so `->where('user_id', 'IS NOT', null)` should also work

Answer (score 1):

U have to use:

```
->where('user_id', 'IS NOT', null)
```

Refer this [document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html):

Answer (score 1):

No `'!='`

The query must be `WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL` so I suppose you must change  `'!='` with `IS NOT`